# Is it possible to configure a serial connection to initiate a program upon receipt of RD signal?

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port

I am currently attempting programming for a serial connection (RS232) through the COM1 port, using hardware handshaking. The OS is Windows XP 32, and I was planning on using C++ to program this (using the .NET serialport class). However, the only way I can currently conceive of doing it is by having a minor program running on start-up, which is continually checking the serial port until direct data is received (through the RxD pin). I was wondering if it's possible to configure the port such that it will open my program once the RD signal is received. Is this at all possible?

Thank you for any help you can give,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple serial port driver which interrupts on RD signal, and have a windows service monitoring the serial port which would receive events from the driver to initiate your program.

Alternatively, depending on the speed of your data, you might be able to simply poll the serial port for RD signal.